# Attach Knex as global object in Vue.js Electron

Tags: vue.js, electron, knex.js, node-sqlite3, electron-vue

I'm using **[SimulatedGREG/electron-vue](https://github.com/SimulatedGREG/electron-vue)** as boiler-plate for electron application. The Application is primarily based on database operation. I want to use the **sqlite3** node native module with **[Knex](https://github.com/knex/knex)** wrapper. How do I use knex with Vue? as the Vue is frontend library and doesn't have access to native APIs, Is it possible? or I must have to use the IPC communication between windows? I have a way to attach the Knex object globally in Vue, as given,

```js
plugins: [
  new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    Knex: 'knex'
  })
]
```

I used jquery globally as given above, but not sure for knex.

Comment: Did you tried to initialize it and just use?

Comment: Didn't tried yet but the question is, sqlite can be used inside Vue component? i need binding way

Comment: is there any update for that ? I'm on the same point.

Comment: @YasinYörük, Yes. I'll post it shortly,